# Using 'for' loop and 'if' statements getting double prints on values over 10

Tags: python, user-input

So I have this loop figured out but with values over 10, the program double prints how much the ticket cost. What is wrong with my code?

```py
age = input("Enter your age to get ticket prices: ")


for ages in age:
    ages = int(age)
    if ages < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free!")
    if 3 <= ages <= 12:
     print("Your ticket is $10")
    if ages > 12:
        print("Your ticket is $15")
```

I was only expecting a single print of whatever print() statement I have set.

Comment: The type of `age` is `str`, so the for-loop will loop over each character that you input into `age` and then translate that character into an integer. If you give it a larger number, say 100, then it will do the same thing, but thrice instead.

Comment: @HampusLarsson How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Rylan-Ferrer, what are you trying to loop over?

Comment: just do age =int( input("Enter your age to get ticket prices: "))

Comment: and u elif and else. not only if's

Comment: @user20194358 Yup this solved it. But what the difference between using input() and int() separately and together?

Comment: @Rylan-Ferrer the function `input("your text here")` in Python(3.x) returns a string, which means that even if you give it a number, the type of that number will still be a string. The function `int()` takes either a string, or a number, and tries to translate that into a number (integer). So calling `int(input("your text here"))` will basically try to cast whatever you input there into an integer immediately. There is no difference between doing that in one line, or doing it on separate lines however, it can sometimes be more convenient to do it on separate lines, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert input to integer like `age = int(input("Enter your age to get ticket prices: "))` and catch the error if it's anything else but a number. You don't really need loop in your case because you check if one number is over  or under certain conditions